# Input field fill but show required after calculate with jQuery in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

adding input field and get in the total field working fine but still get field required error.
here is my code:

```
 jQuery(document , "#esb_subfield_cus_field_bqtshwwnrs").on('keyup', function(){
        var sum = 0;
        jQuery("input[type *= 'number']").each(function(){
            sum+jQuery(this).val();});jQuery('#esb_subfield__price').prop('readonly',true);jQuery("#esb_subfield__price").attr',sum);
        jQuery("#esb_subfield__price").val(sum);
    });
```

Comment: There's nothing about require on here, and you have a syntax error at `jQuery("#esb_subfield__price").attr',sum);`

Comment: I am trying to sum of 6 fields  and get total in another field and its working fine but still get error the field is required

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following changes.

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("#esb_subfield_cus_field_bqtshwwnrs").on('keyup', function(event){
    var sum = 0;
    $("input[type='number']").each(function(i, el){
      sum = sum + parseInt($(el).val());
    });
    $('#esb_subfield__price').val(sum).trigger("change").prop('readonly', true);
  });
});
```

Using `this` in your `.each()` will work, yet it is ambiguous. It is better to make use of `index` and `element` parameters. This way you know you are looking at the proper element. See More: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Remember that `.val()` returns a String. This should be cast to a Integer for Addition. You can use `sum = sum + n` but you can also use `sum += n`, it will provide the same result yet, for me, it helps to see it drawn out, just easier to read later.

Without a complete example, I do not know if `keyup` is the best event to use. `input` might be better.

Consider reading the following: https://wpmudev.com/blog/adding-jquery-scripts-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks for the solution. the total is in the input field and in value as well, but when I submit the form it's given "Total Listing Price field is required. Please enter it value."

Comment: @FurqanAkhtar I added a `change` event before setting `readonly`. This might be needed to help indicate that it has a value for validation. Without the a Minimal, Reproducible Example, there is no way to know why you get this alert.

Comment: I am removing the required field option, when I submit the form its disappear the value and submit